# Why may /dev/shm folder be periodically cleaned in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ipc, shared-memory, ubuntu-18.04

I have a python app which works with /dev/shm folder.
Its processes constantly creates, reads and deletes binary files there in its own /dev/shm/subfolder.
On most Ubuntu servers it works fine without any errors, memory leaks.

However there is one Ubuntu server which has a pretty weird behavior.
Sometimes approximately every hour (but not strictly periodically) the whole /dev/shm folder gets cleaned.
All files and folders there from the app or created manually for example are gone.

The app itself doesn't do it, no other apps, services, daemons were introduced there to do it intentionally. The app can't take more than 20M there which is too far from the limit.

*tmpfs           7.8G  8.3M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm*

Are there any ideas what may be the root cause of the issue?

Comment: Q: Did you look at your system's systemd `RemoveIPC` option?  Was it the culprit?

Comment: Yes, it was, setting RemoveIPC=no fixed the issue, many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for posting back.  Please feel free to "accept" - that makes it likelier someone with the same problem will find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look here:

> [superuser.com: Why are the contents of /dev/shm/ is being removed automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/1117764/why-are-the-contents-of-dev-shm-is-being-removed-automatically)
>
> [Ask Ubuntu: 16.04 LTS and /dev/shm/ Files Disappearing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884127/16-04-lts-and-dev-shm-files-disappearing/884449#884449)
>
> After hours of searching and reading, I found the culprit. It's a
> setting for systemd. The /etc/systemd/logind.conf contains default
> configuration options, with each of them commented out. The RemoveIPC
> option is set to yes by default. That option tells systemd to clean up
> interprocess communication (IPC) for "user accounts" who aren't logged
> in. This does not affect "system accounts"
>
> In my case, the files and directories were being created for a user
> account, not a system account.
>
> There are two possible solutions:
>
> 1. Create the files with/for a system user -- a user created with the system option (adduser -r or adduser --system)
> 2. Edit /etc/systemd/logind.conf, uncomment the line RemoveIPC=yes, change it to RemoveIPC=no, save, and reboot the system
>
> In my case, I went with option #2 because the user was already
> created.

Comment: Only requires a restart `systemctl restart systemd-logind`.